# java 8 map.get multiple key values

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have following code where I want to get value for multiple keys which starts with same name:
for example contents_of_a1, contents_of_ab2, contents_of_abc3

```
Optional.ofNullable(((Map<?, ?>) fieldValue))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(coverages -> coverages.get("contents_of_%"))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(LinkedHashMap.class::isInstance)
                    .map(LinkedHashMap.class::cast)
                    .map(contents -> contents.get("limit"))
                    .map(limit -> new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(limit)))
                    .orElse(new BigDecimal(number));
```

How can I pass contents_of%

Comment: Is it possible for your `Map` to be a `TreeMap`, or something else that can be made to stay in order?  If so, you could probably do something using the `subMap` method.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening in your code? No one aware of the structure of your objects, and this snippet is very far from good coding practices - abuse of `Optional` in order to hide *null-check* and chain methods on it, unchecked type cast.

Comment: This code is quite hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reasons behind the data structure and what you want to achieve.

However, it is not important as this can be easily reproduced.

Using of Optional is a good start, however, for iterating and processing multiple inputs, you need to use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) instead and then Optional inside of collecting (I assume you want `Map<String, BigDecimal` output, but it can be adjusted easily).

Also, note `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` is meaningless as Optional handles `null` internally and is never passed to the next method.

```java
final Map<String, Map<?, ?>> fieldValue = Map.of(
    "contents_of_a", new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of("limit", "10")),
    "contents_of_b", new HashMap<>(Map.of("limit", "11")),         // Different
    "contents_of_c", new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of("amount", "12")),  // No amount
    "contents_of_d", new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of("limit", "13")));

final List<String> contents = List.of(
        "contents_of_a", 
        "contents_of_b", 
        "contents_of_c",
        // d is missing, e is requested instead
        "contents_of_e");

final int number = -1;

final Map<String, BigDecimal> resultMap = contents.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),                               // key
                content -> Optional.of(fieldValue)                 // value
                        .map(coverages -> fieldValue.get(content))
                        .filter(LinkedHashMap.class::isInstance)
                         // casting here to LinkedHashMap is not required
                         // unless its specific methods are to be used
                         // but we only get a value using Map#get
                        .map(map -> map.get("limit"))
                        .map(String::valueOf)
                        .map(BigDecimal::new)
                         // prefer this over orElse as Optional#orElseGet 
                         // does not create an object if not required
                        .orElseGet(() -> new BigDecimal(number))));

// check out the output below the code
resultMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

Only the content for `a` is used as the remaining were either not an instance of `LinkedHashMap`, didn't contain a key `limit` or were not among requested contents.

> ```java
> contents_of_a -> 10
> contents_of_b -> -1
> contents_of_e -> -1
> contents_of_c -> -1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a map for which key starting with "contents_of_", you can do this for Java 8:

```
Map<String, Object> filteredFieldValue = fieldValue.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> {
    String k = e.getKey();
    return Stream.of("contents_of_").anyMatch(k::startsWith);
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```